# Triggering a paramaterized build, and inserting the git branch id

Tags: jenkins-jira-trigger

my jira issue is connected to Git pull requests, and i would like to trigger a jenkins job when a jira status changes. but one of the parameters the jenkins job requires is the branch, how can i pass the branch parameter from my jira issue to jenkins?

more info:

my jenkins build is expecting to get a Git branch name.
[This the information i need to parse from the JIRA issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpExE.png)

so my question is, how do i inject the branch name via [the parameter mapping provided by the Jira-trigger-plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68CGN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this project as Parameterised and pass parameters as `String Parameters`. Just Browse to `Jenkin's Job -> General -> This project is parameterised` and now choose which type of parameter you want. In your case, its a `String Parameter`. Please refer this image.

[image: Jenkins Parameterised Example]

You can access your parameter by `$parameter_name_goes_here`. From above pic parameters are `$JIRA_TICKET_ID` and `$USER_EMAIL`. Hope this helps.

Comment: My parameter for the job is expecting to get a git branch name, and i also have that information in my jira issue under Development. so the jira ticket id is not what i need.

Comment: how are you triggering your build? Did you gone through token setup for that job?

Comment: I did. I edited my original question for more information on what im trying to do exactly

Comment: I do think that branches is a custom field right. Can you able to get the jira ticket id? In the same way please look for that custom field id and then link to it here using `Issue attribute path`

Comment: Yeah i can get the key just fine. the Webhook works, i just need to access the information specified in the picture. How do i know a custom field id?

Comment: Use your developer tools in browser. `Open Developer Tools -> Select Filter XHR` and now look for the url "https://<your domain>.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/<ticket id>" and now get the total json output and then find its value by searching its name.

Comment: Its a dirty process to know though. But works. I hope you have to access it through name itself right..

Comment: I cant enter this url due to it "not being secured". isnt there another way i can view my issue as a JRJC Issue Object?

Comment: As you said **not being secured**, I think you are using the url remotely. So I think you have configured `token`. That is your authentication. Without that, no one can access the job without logging in.